# Is $K(X)$ never algebraically closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I saw an exercise like this:

> Let $K$ be a algebraically closed field. Show that $K(X)$ is not algebraically closed.

I was trying to prove that $T^2-X$ has not root in $K(X)$. How do I show it? Does it really use the hypothesis about $K$?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe show that $X$ has no square root ?

Comment: Degree argument.

Comment: @Xoff: thank you, but I wrote "I was trying to prove that T^2-X has not root in K(X)"

Comment: So if $T=P(X)/Q(X)$ is a root of $T^2-X$, then $P(X)^2=XQ(X)^2$. We indeed have an even degree that is equal to an odd degree ($Q ≠ 0$). So this does not depend on $K$ being algebraically closed?

Comment: As @Bernard said, and no, you don't need to know anything about $K$.

Comment: Related on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/206362/algebraic-closure-of-the-field-of-rational-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments:

If $T=P(X)/Q(X)$ is a root of $T^2-X$, then $P(X)^2=XQ(X)^2$. We indeed have an even degree that is equal to an odd degree ($Q ≠ 0$). This is a contradiction. Therefore, the field $K(X)$ is not algebraically closed, for any field $K$.