# $K(X)$ is not algebraically closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm working through some basic algebra. I'm struggling with the following question:

> Suppose $\beta$ is transcendental over $K$. Prove that $K(\beta)$ is not algebraically closed.

I thought that the Tower law might help, and seek a contraction based on the fact that if transcendental, degree is infinite.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the polynomial
$$
f(X)=X^2-\beta
$$
A root in $K(\beta)$ should be of the form
$$
\frac{P(\beta)}{Q(\beta)}
$$
where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials with coefficients in $K$.

Do you remember the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational?